# ArcGIS Online: possible to build network data set (to be used for distance calculations)

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro (network analyst, OD cost matrix analysis) to calculate distances between a set of points A and a set of points B. Distances are calculated along my own road map, which I have in a shape-file. To do this, I first build a network data set in ArcMap, which I import in ArcGIS Pro prior to the distances calculations.

I am now trying to move my project from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online, and I wonder if it is possible to somehow create the network data set (that I need as input in the OD Cost matrix analysis) in ArcGIS Online? Or do I need to have this ready, and publish it to my ArcGIS Online account in order to perform the distance calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot publish your own routing (network dataset) to ArcGIS Online. You'll need to publish it to your on-premise Enterprise. If you're committed to using ArcGIS Online, you'll need to use the routing services and tools they provide (which are generally credit based consumption)

[Esri staff reference](https://community.esri.com/thread/210814-adding-network-dataset-to-agol) > [Help documentation reference](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/administer/windows/publishing-routing-services.htm)